# Angular ui-router direct from root issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need my application already start at the root, but as I have to use an abstract route had to use a /index soon after the client call.

Following this reasoning has somehow only I call the client name without the /index?

I can not see a way to do it: /

**APP.js**

```
//Routes
.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

    $stateProvider

    .state('client',{
        url      : '/:client',
        abstract : true,

        views: {
            'sidebar@client' : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/sidebar.html',
                cache       : false
            },
            '': {
                templateUrl : 'partials/client.html',
                controller  : 'ClientController',
                cache       : false
            },
        }
    })

    .state('client.index',{
        url           : '/index',
        templateUrl   : 'partials/home.html',
        data          : {
            pageTitle : 'Cardápio Client App'
        }
    })

    .state('client.category',{
        url           : '/c/:category',
        templateUrl   : 'partials/category.html',
        controller    : 'CategoryController',
        data          : {
            pageTitle : 'Categoria Client App'
        }
    });


    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled     : false,
        requireBase : false
    });

})

.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, CLIENTS) {

    $rootScope.$state       = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if(!$rootScope.client) {
            CLIENTS.getList({client: toParams.client})

            .then(function(res){
                $rootScope.client = res[0];
            });
        }

    });

});
```

**LAYOUT client.html**

```
<md-sidenav class="site-sidenav md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="sidebar" ui-view="sidebar"></md-sidenav>
<md-content id="main" layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main" ui-view md-scroll-y flex></md-content>
```

Comment: what you really want

Comment: Simple, I do not want to use /index.. i want to use direct / for example: /: client /